# how do i get correct working pdo server copy of my code

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement, statements

I am new to pdo do to many lession and reading am trying to convert my mysqli code below to pdo server code:

```
    <?php
    include "init.php";
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
    echo "<h2 align='center'>Your shopping cart is empty</h2>";
    exit();
    }
    elseif (!isset($_SESSION["user_name"]) || count($_SESSION["user_name"]) < 1) {
    $book=RAND(1000000, 2000000);
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
    $item_id = $each_item["item_id"];
    $qty = $each_item["quantity"];
    if($item_id =='sms')
    {
    $msg = $each_item["msg"];
    $qty = 1;
    }
    mysqli_query($conn, "insert into books (book, item_name, quantity, msg) values ('$book', '$item_id', '$qty', '$msg')") or die(mysqli_error());
    }
    echo "<div class='info_post'>YOUR SHOPPING BOOKED CODE IS ' . $book . ' KINDLY COPY TO ANY DEALER NEAR YOU TO COMFIRM<br/ ></div><form action='mail.php' method='POST'><b> Mail me:</b><br/ >
    <input type='text' name='book' size='23'> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='SEND EMAIL'></form>";
    unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
    }
    elseif (isset($_SESSION["user_name"]) || count($_SESSION["user_name"]) > 1) {
    $username=$_SESSION["user_name"];
    $query=mysqli_query($conn, "select * from users where username='$username'");
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
    $id=$row["id"];
    $username=$row["username"];
    $ip=$row["ip"];
    $ban=$row["validated"];
    $balance=$row["balance"];
    $buy="$cartTotal";
    {
    if($ban != "0")
    {
    echo "<div class='info_post'><b>$buy $balance $ban</div>";
    }
    }
    if($buy<$balance)
    {
    $redut = $balance-$buy;
    $go = mysqli_query($conn,"update users set balance='$redut' where id='$id'");
    if($go)
    {
    $book=RAND(1000000, 2000000);
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $tem) {
    $m = $tem["item_id"];
    $p = $tem["quantity"];
    $gob = mysqli_query($conn, "insert into books (book, item_name, quantity) values ('$book', '$m', '$p')") or die(mysqli_error());
    $msg = "Transation of $totalquantity products cost of $cartTotal occur on your account with ticket id $book";
    $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    mysqli_query($conn, "insert into details (poster, message, date) values ('$username', '$msg', '$time')") or die(mysqli_error());
    if($gob)
    {
    echo "jamjamja $book";
    unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
    }
    else
    {
    echo "nootjo";
    }
    }
    }
    }
    }
    }
    ?>
```

trying to change all code to be in pdo server here is how my code look like code:

```
    <?php
    include "init.php";
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
    echo "<h2 align='center'>Your shopping cart is empty</h2>";
    exit();
    }
    elseif (!isset($_SESSION["user_name"]) || count($_SESSION["user_name"]) < 1) {
    $book=RAND(1000000, 2000000);
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
    $item_id = $each_item["item_id"];
    $qty = $each_item["quantity"];
    if($item_id =='sms')
    {
    $msg = $each_item["msg"];
    $qty = 1;
    }
    $me = $conn->prepare("insert into books (book,item_name,quantity,msg) values (:book, :m, :p, :d)"); 
    $me->bindParam(':book', $book);
       $me->bindParam(':m', $item_id);
       $me->bindParam(':p', $quantity);
      $me->binParam(':d', $msg);
     $me->execute();
    }
    echo "<div class='info_post'>YOUR SHOPPING BOOKED CODE IS ' . $book . ' KINDLY COPY TO ANY DEALER NEAR YOU TO COMFIRM<br/ ></div><form action='mail.php' method='POST'><b> Mail me:</b><br/ >
    <input type='text' name='book' size='23'> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='SEND EMAIL'></form>";
    unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
    }
    elseif (isset($_SESSION["user_name"]) || count($_SESSION["user_name"]) > 1) {
    $username=$_SESSION["user_name"];
    $records = $conn->prepare("select * from users  where username= :book AND used = loading");
    $records->bindParam(':book', $username);
       $records->execute();

    if($row = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
    $id=$row["id"];
    $username=$row["username"];
    $ip=$row["ip"];
    $ban=$row["validated"];
    $balance=$row["balance"];
    if($ban != "0")
    {
    echo "<div class='info_post'><b>$buy $balance $ban</div>";
    }
    if($buy<=$balance)
    {
    $redut = $balance-$buy;
    $go = $conn->prepare("update users set balance= :redut' where id= :id");
    $go->bindParam(':redut', $redut);
       $go->bindParam(':id', $id);
       $go = $go->execute();
    }
    if($go)
    {
    $book=RAND(1000000, 2000000);
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $tem) {
    $m = $tem["item_id"];
    $p = $tem["quantity"];
    $gob = $conn->prepare("insert into books (book, item_name, quantity) values (:book, :m, :p)"); $gob->bindParam(':book', $book);
       $gob->bindParam(':m', $m);
       $gob->bindParam(':p', $p);
      $gob = $gob->execute();
    $msg = "Transation of $totalquantity products cost of $cartTotal occur on your account with ticket id $book";
    $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $ty = $conn->prepare("insert into details (poster, message, date) values (:username, :msg, :time)"); 
    $ty = bindParam(':username', $username);
    $ty = bindParam(':msg', $msg);
    $ty = bindParam(':time', $time);
    if($gob)
    {
    echo "jamjamja $book";
    unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
    }
    else
    {
    echo "nootjo";
    }
    }
    }
    }
    }
    ?>
```

am sorry to say that using the pdo method my code do not output result when ever a query is sent to ($_SESSION["user_name"]) to be updated into my database and i cant figure out why it do not output result cause am a new pdo statement beginner i believe i we be fine after this.

Can any one figure out why my code do insert record into database?

Comment: Turn on error reporting and you will see that there is no `$conn = new PDO(...);` initiated.

Comment: One problem in one of your queries: `used = loading`.

Comment: If you are looping and doing multiple inserts reuse your prepared statement.

Comment: If $item_id is not 'sms', what will $msg be for your insert?

Comment: In first PDO insert `$quantity !== $qty` ~ also `binParam` should be `bindParam`

Comment: No inset for sms then

Comment: `elseif (isset($_SESSION["user_name"]) || count($_SESSION["user_name"]) > 1)` will this condition ever be satisfied?  Or rather: why count?

Comment: Yes if i get you @progrock

Comment: Typo: `binParam`.

Comment: To begin with you should: 1. turn on error_reporting(E_ALL); then in your init.php make a $pdo = new PDO(

Comment: @halojoy one assumes $conn is a valid pdo connection that is already initialised in init.php (is it?), that's your $pdo.

Comment: i have a very good connection for pdo in init.php

Comment: Getting PDO to throw exceptions may highlight some database related issues: `$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );`  http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php the default is silence.

Answer (score 2):

I firmly believe that using proper code indentation makes it easier to find errors - the code posted is very hard to read "as is" and a number of small mistakes were found and highlighted below.

If you were to use a `try/catch` block around the code you should find it easier to find specific points at which the code fails - a common failure is with `prepared statements` hence using the return value of the `prepare` method as a logic test for throwing new exceptions as below.

Hope it helps

```
<?php
    include "init.php";

    session_start();

    try{

        if( !isset( $_SESSION["cart_array"] ) || count( $_SESSION["cart_array"] ) < 1 ) {

            throw new Exception("<h2 align='center'>Your shopping cart is empty</h2>");

        } elseif( !isset( $_SESSION["user_name"] ) || count($_SESSION["user_name"]) < 1 ) {

            $book = RAND(1000000, 2000000);

            foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {

                $item_id = $each_item["item_id"];
                $qty = $each_item["quantity"];
                $msg='';    #<--------- value?? 

                if( $item_id == 'sms' ) {
                    $msg = $each_item["msg"];
                    $qty = 1;
                }

                $me = $conn->prepare("insert into books (book,item_name,quantity,msg) values (:book, :m, :p, :d)");
                if( !$me )throw new Exception('Failed to prepare sql statement',1);

                $me->bindParam(':book', $book );
                $me->bindParam(':m', $item_id );
                $me->bindParam(':p', $qty );    #<-------- not quantity
                $me->bindParam(':d', $msg );    #<-------- bindParam not binParam
                $me->execute();
            }

            echo "
            <div class='info_post'>YOUR SHOPPING BOOKED CODE IS ' . $book . ' KINDLY COPY TO ANY DEALER NEAR YOU TO COMFIRM<br/ ></div>
            <form action='mail.php' method='POST'><b> Mail me:</b><br/ >
                <input type='text' name='book' size='23'>
                <input type='submit' name='submit' value='SEND EMAIL'>
            </form>";

            unset( $_SESSION["cart_array"] );

        } elseif( isset($_SESSION["user_name"]) || count($_SESSION["user_name"]) > 1) {

            $username = $_SESSION["user_name"];
            $records = $conn->prepare("select * from users  where username= :book AND used = loading");     #<--------- loading?? an unbound parameter perhaps?
            if( !$records )throw new Exception('Failed to prepare sql statement',2);

            $records->bindParam(':book', $username);

            #$records->bindParam(':loading', $loading);     #<---------- is there supposed to be a second bound parameter?
            $records->execute();



            if ( $row = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH) ) {

                $id = $row["id"];
                $username = $row["username"];
                $ip = $row["ip"];
                $ban = $row["validated"];
                $balance = $row["balance"];

                if ( $ban != "0" ) {
                    echo "<div class='info_post'><b>$buy $balance $ban</div>";
                }

                if ($buy <= $balance) {
                    $redut = $balance - $buy;

                    $go = $conn->prepare("update users set balance= :redut' where id=:id");
                    if( !$go ) throw new Exception('Failed to prepare sql statement',4);

                    $go->bindParam(':redut', $redut);
                    $go->bindParam(':id', $id);
                    $go = $go->execute();
                }

                if ($go) {

                    $book = RAND(1000000, 2000000);
                    foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $tem) {

                        $m = $tem["item_id"];
                        $p = $tem["quantity"];

                        $gob = $conn->prepare("insert into books (book, item_name, quantity) values (:book, :m, :p)");
                        if( !$gob )throw new Exception('Failed to prepare sql statement',5);

                        $gob->bindParam(':book', $book);
                        $gob->bindParam(':m', $m);
                        $gob->bindParam(':p', $p);
                        $gob = $gob->execute();

                        $msg = "Transation of $totalquantity products cost of $cartTotal occur on your account with ticket id $book";
                        $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                        $ty = $conn->prepare("insert into details (poster, message, date) values (:username, :msg, :time)");
                        if( !$ty ) throw new Exception('Failed to prepare sql statement',6);

                        $ty = bindParam(':username', $username);
                        $ty = bindParam(':msg', $msg);
                        $ty = bindParam(':time', $time);

                        if ($gob) {
                            echo "jamjamja $book";
                            unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
                        }
                        else {
                            echo "nootjo";
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                throw new Exception('No records found',3);
            }
        }

    } catch( Exception $e ){
        printf( 'Error: Code %d Message %s', $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage() );
    }

?>
```

---

Had another look at your original and the suggestions I made previously after reading your comment and quickly put the following together ~ slightly different logic perhaps but I think still follows the original.

I tried to move the `prepare` method calls outside of any loops ( as they should be ) along with the `bindParam` calls, re-used the `$stmt` object name but ensured the `$stmt` object was closed after use.

The question still remains - what is `loading` in the sql - if it is a placeholder what value does it take and from where is that value derived?

```
<?php

    include 'init.php';

    session_start();

    try{
        if( empty( $_SESSION['cart_array'] ) ){
            throw new Exception('<h2 align="center">Your shopping cart is empty</h2>');
        } else {
            if( empty( $_SESSION['user_name'] ) ){
                $book = rand( 1000000, 2000000 );

                /* Prepare SQL once outside the loop */
                $sql = 'insert into `books` ( `book`,`item_name`, `quantity`, `msg` ) values ( :book, :item, :qty, :msg )';
                $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
                if( $stmt ){

                    /* bind placholders to variables */
                    $stmt->bindParam(':book', $book );
                    $stmt->bindParam(':item', $id );
                    $stmt->bindParam(':qty', $qty );
                    $stmt->bindParam(':msg', $msg );

                    /* assign variables and execute inside loop */
                    foreach( $_SESSION['cart_array'] as $item ) {

                        $id  = $item['item_id'];
                        $qty = $item['quantity'];
                        $msg = '';

                        if( $id == 'sms' ) {
                            $msg = $item['msg'];
                            $qty = 1;
                        }

                        $stmt->execute();
                    }
                    $stmt->closeCursor();



                    echo "
                    <div class='info_post'>
                        YOUR SHOPPING BOOKED CODE IS ' . $book . ' KINDLY COPY TO ANY DEALER NEAR YOU TO COMFIRM
                        <br/ >
                    </div>
                    <form action='mail.php' method='POST'><b> Mail me:</b><br/ >
                        <input type='text' name='book' size='23'>
                        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='SEND EMAIL' />
                    </form>";

                    unset( $_SESSION['cart_array'] );

                } else {
                    throw new Exception('Failed to prepare sql statement',1);
                }   
            } else {

                /* create and prepare sql */
                $sql='select * from `users`  where `username`=:book';
                $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );

                /* bind parameters */
                if( $stmt ){

                    $stmt->bindParam(':book', $username );

                    $username = $_SESSION['user_name'];

                    $result = $stmt->execute();

                    if( $result ){

                        $row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_BOTH );
                        $stmt->closeCursor();

                        if( !$row ) throw new Exception('bad foo',3);

                        /* assign vars */
                        $id         = $row['id'];
                        $username   = $row['username'];
                        $ip         = $row['ip'];
                        $ban        = $row['validated'];
                        $balance    = $row['balance'];


                        if( $ban != "0" ) {
                            echo "<div class='info_post'><b>$buy $balance $ban</div>";
                        }

                        if( $buy <= $balance) {
                            $redut = $balance - $buy;

                            $sql='update `users` set `balance`=:redut where `id`=:id;';
                            $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );

                            if( $stmt ){
                                $stmt->bindParam(':redut', $redut );
                                $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id );

                                $result = $stmt->execute();
                                $stmt->closeCursor();

                                if( $result ){

                                    $book = rand( 1000000, 2000000 );

                                    $sql_insert_1='insert into `books` ( `book`, `item_name`, `quantity` ) values ( :book, :name, :qty )';
                                    $stmt_insert_1=$conn->prepare( $sql );

                                    $sql_insert_2='insert into `details` ( `poster`, `message`, `date` ) values ( :username, :msg, :time )';
                                    $stmt_insert_2=$conn->prepare( $sql );


                                    if( $stmt_insert_1 ){
                                        $stmt_insert_1->bindParam(':book', $book );
                                        $stmt_insert_1->bindParam(':name', $name );
                                        $stmt_insert_1->bindParam(':qty', $qty );
                                    } else {
                                        throw new Exception('Failed to prepare sql statement',5);
                                    }


                                    if( $stmt_insert_2 ){
                                        $stmt_insert_2->bindParam(':username', $username );
                                        $stmt_insert_2->bindParam(':msg', $msg );
                                        $stmt_insert_2->bindParam(':time', $time );
                                    } else {
                                        throw new Exception('Failed to prepare sql statement',6);
                                    }


                                    foreach( $_SESSION['cart_array'] as $item ) {

                                        /* $book defined above - rand() */
                                        $name = $item['item_id'];
                                        $qty = $item['quantity'];

                                        /* $username defined earlier */
                                        $msg = "Transation of $totalquantity products cost of $cartTotal occur on your account with ticket id $book";
                                        $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


                                        $result = $stmt_insert_1->execute();
                                        if( !$result )throw new Exception('insert failed',7);

                                        $result = $stmt_insert_2->execute();
                                        if( !$result )throw new Exception('insert failed',8);

                                    }

                                    $stmt_insert_1->closeCursor();
                                    $stmt_insert_2->closeCursor();

                                    unset( $_SESSION['cart_array'] );
                                }
                            } else {
                                throw new Exception('Failed to prepare sql statement',4);
                            }
                        }   
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new Exception('Failed to prepare sql statement',2);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch( Exception $e ){
        printf( 'Error: Code %d Message %s', $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage() );
    }

?>
```

Comment: the first steatment work very fine just as expected but if recore exist in $_SESSION["user_name"] the page do not process

Comment: where do you mean?

Comment: I dont really no about loading in my code line i think i miss wright it then but in my code i remove it couse i have no placehold for it and every thing seem to work very fine but on condiction. first statement is working very fine as expected but if record exist $_SESSION['user_name'] the page process only on refress not on visit and $_SESSION['cart_array'] do not unset after this process.
this is how i place my code
please see it: https://ideone.com/tQSQVX

Comment: can you indicate which portion of code you are referring to?

Comment: The above statement work very fine the issue is from here thanks so much for your time.
code beggining from here below
else {
     
     /* create and prepare sql */
     $sql='select * from `users`  where `username`=:book;'; # <---- what is this parameter ??
     $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
     
     /* bind parameters */
     if( $stmt ){
     etc...